# Protractor.js:Error while loading the page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor, e2e-testing

I am new to `protractor.js`.
I have a scenario where I am getting the page to be tested and in that page I am finding an element to click and then redirect to some other page.

`config.js`:

```
exports.config = {
seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',

capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome'
},
rootElement: '.apt.ui',

specs: ['./protractor-tests/homeTest.js'],

jasmineNodeOpts: {
    showColors: true
}
```

};

home test page:

These are the test case which I wrote to implement the scenario.

```
describe('Home Test', function() {
it('It should click product', function() {
    var targetUrl = 'http://domain/home';
    browser.get(targetUrl);

})
it('looking for the product', function() {
    browser.waitForAngular();
    var productMenu = element(By.xpath('/html/body/div[1]/headerdiv[1]/section/div[1]/apt-nav-bar/div/div[2]/div[2]/ul/li[2]/a/span'));
    productMenu.isPresent();
    productMenu.click();
    expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).not.toEqual('http://domain/home');
    expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toEqual('http://domain/products');
})
```

});

but when I run this I am getting the error:

```
 Message:
Failed: Error while waiting for Protractor to sync with the page: "Cannot read property '$$testability' of undefined"
```

I don't understand this .
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Which version Protractor are you using?

Comment: Check rootElement: '.apt.ui', value. make user that you mentioned css locator for <tag> where "ng-app" directive is placed in login.html or index.html

Answer (score 0):

This was an issue with Protractor, which has been mentioned [here](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/4233). Please read through the issue. This issue has been fixed in `Protractor 5.1.2`. Please update your protractor and if you're still able to reproduce this, please submit an issue with the Protractor team.